# Add default option to every command invocation?

Tags: koma-script, pandoc

I'm using KOMAscript and pandoc to write a document. The KOMAscript has a nifty `nonumber=true` option I can use with `\chapter` ([doc](https://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf), p.103). But since I'm using a pandoc template, the `\chapter` invocations will be automatic.

Is there a way to make it so that every `\chapter{..}` will actually be `\chapter[nonumber=true]{..}` ?

Comment: This extended interpretation of the optional argument to `\chapter` is not available by default and requires that you set a specific KOMA option (`headings` with one of the values `optiontohead`, `optiontotoc` or `optiontoheadandtoc`). If you have enough control over the document preamble to do that, you might as well just deactivate the chapter numbering.

Comment: Couldn't you use either `\addchap` instead of `\chapter` or set `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}`?